# Graph database / client for Python?

Tags: database, python, nosql

I need a graph database usable from Python. The goal is representing email communications like "X contacted Y on Jan 10th who on Jan 20th contacted Z", etc.

I loved to see Bulbs: https://github.com/espeed/bulbs but it seems like it's not been updated in a while.

Questions:

1. Is Bulbs abandoned or simply stable?
2. Please recommend solutions to which you've had at least some practical exposure.

Comment: Have tried any of the options at https://github.com/espeed/bulbs#where-can-i-get-help to see if the reason that there haven't been any updates is simply that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Neo4J](http://neo4j.com/) with the [py2neo](http://py2neo.org/) client with success. Bulbs seems clearly no longer maintained especially with PR pending for close to 5 years and this [kind of unanswered ticket](https://github.com/espeed/bulbs/issues/159).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Memgraph. There is a lot of [content related to Python](https://memgraph.com/blog?topics=Python#list). Also there is [GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy). It is an open-source Python library and an Object Graph Mapper (OGM) - a link between graph database objects and Python objects.